# Append Fancybox DIV to Form tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, fancybox, partial-views

Fancybox is appending it's DIV tags at the bottom of my DOM.  Is there a way to get it to append within the FORM tag?  I am binding it to an element within the form tag but when I inspect the document in Chrome the Fancybox DIV is being added at the bottom.

The reason for this is I am using MVC3 and loading a partial view in the fancybox.  That part is working.  The fields in fancybox are being excluded by the model binder upon postback because they are outside the FORM.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".clickMe").fancybox({
        content: $('#test')
      });
    });
  });//]]>  
</script>


<body>
  <form id='testform'>
    <a href="#emailViewFancybox" class="clickMe">Click Me</a>
  </form>
  <div style="display: none;" id='test'>
     Tri-tip brisket ribeye fatback ground round pork chop. Strip steak tenderloin t-bone tri-tip, spare ribs tongue prosciutto meatloaf. Beef ribs ham sirloin, biltong ham hock venison jowl andouille flank pork belly. Meatball strip steak chicken, capicola prosciutto hamburger spare ribs.
  </div>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems with JQuery dialogs as parts of forms. I ended up having to use javascript to move the generated divs into the forms after they were generated.

Comment: Thanks.  I used jquery's .appendTo() to move the div I need inside the form and it worked.